# How to add new page in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

Do I have to create a new own page? can not understand the theme structure on which file or module I have which files. Can Explain me in details?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you want to **create a custom frontend page in Magento 2**. So here is the process

**Basic Module setup (Required for any new module in Magento 2):**

**Step 1:** Create module’s main configuration file module.xml in below directory: `magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/etc/module.xml`

**Step2:** Create module’s resgistration.php inside below directory `magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/registration.php`

**Step3:** Now run command as php bin/magento module:status (To list out all enabled or disabled module in the system)

**Step 4:** Now run command as `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` (To list out all enabled or disabled module in the system)

Now our new module will be listed in `Store-Configuration-Advanced-Advanced`

**Now write logic for frontend module (Custom Frontend Page):**

**Step 5:** Add routes.xml in below directory

```
magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/etc/frontend/routes.xml
```

**Step6:** Add controller in below directorymagento2 `magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/Controller/Test/Helloworld.php`

**Step7:** Now we need frontend layout in below directory `magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_test_helloworld.xml`

**Step8:** Now add a block file in below directory `magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/Block/Helloworld.php`

**Step9:** Add a `.phtml` file we used in layout `magento2_akhil/app/code/Akhil/Test/View/frontend/template/helloworld.phtml`

**Step10:** Now run below commands `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` Clear Browser Caching

**Step11:** Open the URL as: `http://localhost/magento2_akhil/helloworld/test/helloworld`

**Detailed Description here** [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf-XOKpYpME&index=4&list=PLpyJOWPazA_CQjWQY5JUirpR6uHgHOmBc)